# Invert transform of a generating function

Tags: generating-functions, transformation

[A055887](https://oeis.org/A055887)'s generating function is given as a transform of another generating function $\frac{1}{1-P(x)}$. It's clear from the definition that this is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left [ \sum_{i+j+k+...=n} P(i)P(j)P(k)... \right ] x^n$ but I'm struggling to derive this.

I've seen $x$ in $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1+x+x^2+x^3$ be replaced $x$ with $a x$, $x^2$, $x^m$, $-x$ but I only proved these by working backwards. Starting with the result and showing
$S - Sx = 1$ then concluding $S = \frac{1}{1-x}$.

This was called "invert transform" in [A067687](https://oeis.org/A067687) but that term doesn't seem to be [defined](https://oeis.org/wiki/Sequence_transforms) or commonly used outside of OEIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** A proof of
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\left(1-A(z)\right)^{-1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}A^n(z)}
\end{align*}
with constant term of $A(z)$ equal to zero is given *[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4589281/formal-powerseries-compute-the-reciprocal-of-1-az-for-a-0-ne-0/4590691#4590691)*.